# How to check a string in JavaScript and return Boolean?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

How would I convert the following statements to JavaScript?

```
Set oTextRange = frmSearch.OrderNumList.createTextRange()
lFound = oTextRange.FindText(aOrderNumList(nI))
```

`lFound` should be a Boolean value.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code converting tool.

Comment: Start here for IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . And JavaScript in MSDN: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=249010 . MDN link you can find from my answer to your previous similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lFound = oTextRange.indexOf(aOrderNumList(nI))!=-1
```

Comment: @Cerbrus: Stop calling out people for answering crappy questions as long as the answer is not crap, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`String.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

SO is not a code sample site, but we can give you a nudge in the right direction.